# Error handling with libxml functions

Tags: c, xml, libxml2

Here are some links documenting the functions that I want to use:

- [xmlNewNode](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlNewNode)
- [xmlNewChild](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlNewChild)
- [xmlNewProp](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlNewProp)

Since these functions use dynamic memory allocation, I want to do error checking, but I couldn't find information about behavior of these functions in case of an error. Do these functions simply return NULL on failure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, like most of the `libxml2` functions which return pointers, these return `NULL` on failure.

Comment: How do you know this ?

Comment: Just have a look at the [source code](https://git.gnome.org/browse/libxml2/tree/tree.c).